# emailing an image picked by user from UIpickerController

Tags: iphone, ios4, uiimagepickercontroller

what i want to in my app is have a user select an image in their library, then attach that image to an email and send it.

i have read multiple examples, but cant seem to get any to work with this

```
- (IBAction)buttonTouched:(id)sender;
```

{
    // Create image picker controller
    UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];

```
// Set source to the camera
imagePicker.sourceType =  UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;

// Delegate is self
imagePicker.delegate = self;

// Allow editing of image ?
```

//  imagePicker.allowsImageEditing = NO;

```
// Show image picker
[self presentModalViewController:imagePicker animated:YES];
```

}

this is the code i tried to get the image at a button press. but how do i get that into the email, i just dont understand how this returns the image and in what format

any help would be very welcome :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have the same request some weeks ago, you have to display the UIImagePickerController and let the user select an image, and save it in a variable.

```
UIImage *image;
```

Next implemente the method:

```
// Displays an email composition interface inside the application. Populates all the Mail fields. 
-(void)displayComposerSheet 
{
    MFMailComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    picker.mailComposeDelegate = self;

    [picker setSubject:@"This is my subject"];


    // Set up recipients
    NSArray *toRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"personOne@example.com"]; 

    [picker setToRecipients:toRecipients];

    // Attach an image to the email
    NSData *myData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.image);
    [picker addAttachmentData:myData mimeType:@"image/png" fileName:@"myImage"];

    [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
    [picker release];
}
```